# How do I make several objects refer to one common array?

Tags: java

Program creates several `Example` objects that each must add their own number into one array. The problem is that each object refers to its own array, not the common one. How do I make objects refer to one common array?

My code:

```java
class Example {
    private int[] array = new int[5];
    private int number;

    public Example(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void addInArr(int x) {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if(array[i]==0) {
                array[i] = x;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public void showArr() {
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i=1; i<6; i++) {
            Example obj = new Example(i);
            obj.addInArr(i);
            obj.showArr();
        }
    }
}
```

The code outputs: `1 0 0 0 0  2 0 0 0 0  3 0 0 0 0  4 0 0 0 0  5 0 0 0 0`

The code must output: `1 2 3 4 5`

Comment: Where are threads used in your snippet?

Comment: I removed the word "thread" from your question. Your program does not create any threads, nor is there anything about it suggesting that you wanted to create threads.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest is to define the array as a static member of the class.

```
public class StaticExample {
  private static int[] array = new int[5];
  ...
  public int getLength() {
    return array.length;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main thread is working in the same array. Your problem has nothing about multithreading. Your addInArray() method logic is not correct. You have 5 spots in your array but you always adds the new value at position 0. So the others spots are 0 as the default value for int.

You likely need a new variable to store the current position of your array starting as 0.

```
private int position = 0;

public void addInArr(int x) {
   array[position] = x;
   position++;
}
```

Attention: If you add more than five numbers it will generate an error because your array has only 5 slots.